AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: context not currently entered; can't exit . Error when POSTING DATA TO thirdparty API
AM using Node 20 version and npm 10 .
The code was working fine with node 12 previously .  All the Apis are working fine with CLSHOOK VERSION 4.2.2 but i have few Apis which are posting data to thirdparty apis using fetch .
when i hit those api then the app crashes when it reaches the fetch function . below is my middleware for cls-hooked
 app.use(function (req, res, next) {

context.bindEmitter(req);
context.bindEmitter(res);

 context.run(function () {

// set tid on the namespace, makes it
// available for all continuations
context.set('request:id', req.id);
context.set('request:x-app-language', req.headers['x-app-language']);
next();
});

});



//Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(reqLogger.log);

app.use('/', Index);
app.use('/api', apiR);

and below is my that code where this Error happens
   // make fetch call
    console.log('cmslogcomplaint before fetch Call');
   //  error happens after above statement prints

    let response;
    let result;
    try {

        response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(requestArgs),
            headers: {
                Authorization: header,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        
        result = await response.json();
        console.log('success')

    } catch (error) {
  
        console.log('loggy cmps api error', error);
        throw new Error("Something went wrong. please try later.")
    }

Please Note that all above works fine for node 12 but now i have upgraded to Nodejs 20 and clshook version is 4.2.2 Moreover i also cannot use Async hooks for now as i have to change code on lot of places. and  all other routes are working  wether get or post . here is exception
